# Genexus Cambiar Base Datos

Tags: genexus, genexusxev3

Tengo una app web desarrollada en GeneXus X Ev3 (10.3.115824 U15) que utiliza una base de datos SQL Server.

La aplicación compila y genera DLLs sin problemas, las cuales luego de generadas, copio en el ambiente de testing (otro server).

Mi problema, es que necesito compilar en el opc de desarrollo, y también quiero ejecutar en el mismo equipo (con una copia de la base de datos de testing), pero al momento de iniciar la aplicación (aparecer la pantalla de login) pero al ingresar un usuario, me aparece un error de conecion a la base de datos, en donde se indica que no puede encontrar el server.

He revisado el archivo web.config, y la información donde se indica el servidor, base de datos, usuario y contraseña se encuentran encriptados dentro del subsegmento .

he intentado eliminar el archivo web.config, para que genexus genere uno nuevo, pero lo que resulta es el mismo archivo que elimine previamente, con los nombres del server (de testing) encriptados.

He buscado en el proyecto, donde especificar los nombres de la base de datos el servidor y el usuario, pero no he podido dar con el lugar en esta versión.

Alguien sabe donde puedo especificar estos parámetros?

Saludos y gracias por su tiempo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dentro del directorio `bin` hay un ejecutable de nombre `gxconfig.exe`. Éste es el que hace la reconfiguración del `web.config`.

Por lo tanto, debes copiar el `web.config` al directorio `bin`, cambiar lo que quieres y copiar el archivo de vuelta al directorio `web`.

Comment: Hola, gracias por la respuesta, funciono sin problemas.